# Need to show navigation title while using searchBar in navigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I need to show large navigation title while search with searchBar, but when I'm clicking on Searchbar or starting to type my NavigationTitle is replaced with SearchBar. I checked methods for navigationItem and didn't find any suitable.

Does anybody know how can we always show title, even while searching?
Here is my code

```
    class FavouriteVC: UIViewController {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            view.backgroundColor = .white
            
            navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationItem.title = "Favourite"
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        }
    }
```

And here are shots
[screen with NavTitle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp6JC.jpg)
[screen without NavTitle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahqgM.jpg)

Comment: Hey! If I'm not mistaken, my answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `UISearchController` has a `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` that prevents the navigation bar from hiding when set to `false`

Include:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

in your `viewDidLoad` and if I've understood your issue right, this should do what you need.